# Qtable index out of bounds

Tags: grid, artificial-intelligence, q-learning, gml, game-maker-studio-2

Im trying to make a simple Q-learning AI in gms2, but im horrible messing with grinds and aways get the same problem when i try to update the qTable:

```
index out of bounds
```

project is simple, the AI can go to all directions and need to touch the "obj_goal" while avoid the "obj_obstacles"

Create event:

```
QTableWidth = 100; // Ajuste o tamanho conforme necessário
QTableHeight = 100; // Ajuste o tamanho conforme necessário
QTable = ds_grid_create(QTableWidth, QTableHeight);


learningRate = 0.1;
discountFactor = 0.9;
explorationRate = 0.7;

reward = 0;


currentX = x;
currentY = y;


iniX = x;
iniY = y;




spd = 2;
```

step event:

```
function getCurrentState() {
    return string(currentX) + string("_") + string(currentY);
}

id_action = choose(0, 1, 2, 3);


currentX = x;
currentY = y;
currentState = getCurrentState();

#region randomizar ou andar com base em aprendizado
if random(1) < explorationRate {
    // Exploração (ação aleatória)
    action = choose("up", "down", "left", "right");
} else {
    var bestActionIndex = 0;
    var bestActionValue = QTable[# currentState, 0];
    for (var i = 1; i < QTableHeight; i++) {
        var value = QTable[# currentState, i];
        if (value > bestActionValue) {
            bestActionValue = value;
            bestActionIndex = i;
        }
    }
    action = bestActionIndex;
}
#endregion

#region açoes
switch (action) {
    case "up":
        y -= spd;
        break;
    case "down":
        y += spd;
        break;
    case "left":
        x -= spd;
        break;
    case "right":
        x += spd;
        break;
}
#endregion

if place_meeting(x, y, obj_objetivo) {
    reward += 10;
    
    x = iniX;
    y = iniY;
} else if place_meeting(x, y, obj_Obstaculo) {
    reward -= 10;
    
    x = iniX;
    y = iniY;
}

newState = getCurrentState();

var currentStateIndex = floor(currentState);
var idActionIndex = floor(id_action);



if currentState >= 0 && currentState < QTableWidth && id_action >= 0 && id_action < QTableHeight {


    QTable[# currentState, id_action] += learningRate * (reward + discountFactor * QTable[# newState, id_action] - QTable[# currentState, id_action]);
    
} else {
    show_debug_message("index out of bounds.");
}

currentX = x;
currentY = y;
```

it was supossed to update the Qtable to make the AI learn with the rewards that was given.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to be using any grid-specific functions anyway, you could swap it for a 2d array - that will throw a proper error on out-of-bounds access. Initialization would have to be done like so:

```
QTable = array_create(QTableWidth);
for (var i = 0; i < QTableWidth; i++) QTable[i] = array_create(QTableHeight, 0);
```

You can run the game in debug mode to inspect the local/instance variables at the time of error.